# Image tags are not rendering image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I need to render 360 pictures (base64 data) and a video (that is about 2GB).

I tested playing the video and pictures with jssor slider but I got an error. That is looks like low GPU working. Because I saved base64 data in a javascript value, so I thought that is working well. However after about a hour images are not working so I don't  know how to fix it.

I used animations when changing images:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
  col_transitions[i] = [{
      b: 0,
      d: 4000,
      sX: 2,
      sY: 2,
      e: {
        sX: 13,
        sY: 13
      }
    },
    {
      b: 4000,
      d: 3000,
      r: 360,
      e: {
        r: 4
      }
    }, //200,10
    {
      b: 7000,
      d: 3000,
      r: -360,
      e: {
        r: 4
      }
    }, //200,10
    {
      b: 10000,
      d: 4000,
      sX: -1.8,
      sY: -1.8,
      e: {
        sX: 13,
        sY: 13
      }
    },
    {
      b: 14000,
      d: 1600,
      x: 100,
      y: 70
    }, //100,70
    {
      b: 15600,
      d: 1600,
      x: -150,
      y: -20
    }, //-50,50
    {
      b: 17200,
      d: 1600,
      x: 50,
      y: -50,
      sX: -0.2,
      sY: -0.2
    }
  ];

  $("#slick_list").find("div[data-u=slides]").append("<div><img data-u=\"image\" data-t=\"" + i + "\"/></div>");
}
//I missed this code sorry
  $("#slick_list").find("div[data-u=slides]").append(
    "<div style=\"position:relative;\">"+
      "<video class=\"video1\" onended=\"video_end(1)\">"+
        "<source src=\"videos\/s1.mov\" type=\"video\/mp4\">"+
      "</video>"+
      "<img src=\"\"/>"+
    "</div>"
  );
```

Video is on LocalPc and pictures are from remote server and that call is need lower then 2sec and that is using jsonp type. call point is before image is visible then next image are starting load.

Image datas will be on array. so after loading datas that is not loading anymore. If images are not enough(I mean lower then 360) then img tags will be reloading at first image. like a cycle(?).

(example)

```
if(max_page !== null){
      page = img_cnt%(max_page+1);
    }else{
      page = img_cnt;
    }
```

The code above works well until about 200 pictures. I don't have any idea what to do. Please help me.

---

I used this function when i load some image and before to display

```
function load_image(){
    var img_path;
    if(max_page !== null){
      page = img_cnt%(max_page+1);
    }else{
      page = img_cnt;
    }
    if(eval("typeof img_dataArr._"+page)==="undefined"){
      $.ajax({
        async:false,
        cache :false,
        url : "{address}",
        jsonpCallback:"CB",
        crossDomain:true,
        method:"get",
        dataType :"jsonp",
        success:function(data){
          var image_data = decodeURIComponent(data['file']);
          eval("img_dataArr._"+page+"=\"data:image/png;base64,\"+image_data");
          if(data['max_cnt']) {
            max_page = page;
          }
        },
        error:function(e){
          max_page = page;
        },
        complete:function(data){
          if(!((img_cnt-2)<0)){
            $('#slick_list').find("div[data-u=slides]").last().find('img').eq(img_cnt-2).attr('src',"");
          }else{
            $('#slick_list').find("div[data-u=slides]").last().find('img').eq(360+img_cnt-2).attr('src',"");
          }
          $('#slick_list').find("div[data-u=slides]").last().find('img').eq(img_cnt).attr('src',eval("img_dataArr._"+page));
          $('#slick_list').find("div[data-u=slides]").last().find('img').eq(img_cnt).css("display","inline");
          img_cnt = img_cnt+1;
        }
      });
    }else{
      if(!(((img_cnt%list_size)-2)<0)){
        $('#slick_list').find("div[data-u=slides]").last().find('img').eq(img_cnt%list_size-2).attr('src',"");
      }else{
        $('#slick_list').find("div[data-u=slides]").last().find('img').eq(360+img_cnt%list_size-2).attr('src',"");
      }
      $('#slick_list').find("div[data-u=slides]").last().find('img').eq(img_cnt%list_size).attr('src',eval("img_dataArr._"+page));
      $('#slick_list').find("div[data-u=slides]").last().find('img').eq(img_cnt%list_size).css("display","inline");
      img_cnt = img_cnt+1;
    }
  }
```

As on clearly that is working well but after about 200+ pictures not working but video was playing well.

---

I checked Performance on chrome.

And on there able to see that position.
That problem is a memory. cuz that is able to see on [image]

How can i fix it...??

Comment: I would not visit a webpage with 360 base64 pictures being produced based on my computing power, plus load a 2GB video. You need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: that is working on localhost and using url is like this 
file://c:/{file_path}

Comment: Image size is 1280*768. just that is look like a presentation

Comment: Localhost (where the data is being read directly from your HDD) is a lot different to a remote server (where the data is being transferred over your much slower internet connection). Not to mention the fact you're flooding the server with 300+ image requests as well as streaming the video. I'm more surprised it works at all.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What is your point exactly? **For the browser** it makes absolutely no difference (with regard to memory consumption at least) where the server is located. It will request the data from the server just as if it were a remote one (except for cross-origin rules). Localhost should even consume twice as much memory as a remote server: the data should be read from HDD + sent from server + decoded on browser as a normal remote request. Time to load it has also no incidence on the memory that will be used.

Comment: @Kaiido that is clean base64 data. So i loaded 5 pictures first and a picture are loading on a page about 360/{loaded pictures} times. 
but i can't load after 40 times.
so i guess that is a kind of memory problems. just i guessed.
and i that was correct i think.

Comment: Yes but why as ajax loaded b64? If you did load the files directly as what they are, then browsers could at least cache it, and wouldn't have to store it three times in memory: once as b64 string, once as binary, once as uncompressed image pixels.

Comment: @Kaiido cuz the img tags are reload image datas when visible. 
but that connection is able to cutdown. so I think that is hard to fix, and need to using another way. so I did like this.. but i got a like this problems.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your opinions. I saved base64 to File obj and get URL from obj. So Performance was going better but same results.